# How do I make a range of numbers print off only as double digits?

Tags: powershell, scripting, digits

I need to be able to print off a range of numbers only as double digits. For example, `01,02,03,04...10,11`.

https://forums.overclockers.co.uk/threads/powershell-convert-1-digit-number-to-2-digit-number.18279138/

This is the script I am trying it in:

```
# Define a range's upper bound dynamically (IRL via user input)
$upperBound = 18

# Create an array of numbers (indices).
1..$upperBound
```

I tried using "{0:D2}" as the above site stated but I got a error "Cannot convert value":

```
1.."{0:D2}" -f $upperBound
```

I also tried this;

```
"{0:D2}" -f $upperBound
```

However, this only display the one number that was entered, not the entire range. For example, if I enter 2, I will get 02. I would like it to display 01,02.

In addition to this, I would like this range to be displayed next to a server name. I have a list of servers and this range would have to be attached to the server name. Example:

```
server01
server02
```

Comment: I would argue that your issue is your using `-f $upperbound` which is cuasing it to look at '18' as the digit you're wanting. as the chosen answer is separating it via a loop. This allows it to do each number, instead of just '18'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The range operator (`..`) only operates on *numbers* as endpoints; in order to format the resulting array of numbers you must apply *post-processing* on the elements of the array created by `..`:

Note: The sample output below assumes that `$upperBound` has a value of `3`.

Using PSv4+ syntax:

```
PS> (1..$upperBound).ForEach({ '{0:D2}' -f $_ })
01
02
03
```

In PSv3-, use:

```
foreach ($ndx in 1..$upperBound) { '{0:D2}' -f $ndx } # same output as above.
```

To make the formatted "number strings" part of a server name:

```
PS> (1..$upperBound).ForEach({ 'server{0:D2}' -f $_ })
server01
server02
server03
```

---

In order to create a *list* of names as a *single string with separators*, use the `-join` operator on the resulting array:

```
PS> (1..$upperBound).ForEach({ 'server{0:D2}' -f $_ }) -join ','
server01,server02,server03
```

In PSv3-:

```
$(foreach ($ndx in 1..$upperBound) { 'server{0:D2}' -f $ndx }) -join ','
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$upperbound = 18
$totalArray = 1..$upperbound | foreach {$_.tostring('00')}
foreach ($server in (cat serverlist.txt)) {
    $totalarray | foreach {"$server$_"}
}
```

replace 00 with how many places you want 0's to take

0 = 1,2,3 etc..

00 = 01, 02, 03 etc...

000 = 001, 002, 003 etc..

if you want to display server digits in a single line with commas you could just do

```
$totalArray -join ','
```